# How do I alias this in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, script, shell-script, powershell-5.0

I would like to alias the rather wordy command, `Remove-WebApplication -Name portal -Site "Default Site"`, but when I try:

`Set-Alias RemPortal Remove-WebApplication -Name portal -Site "Default Site"`

I get the error:

`A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Remove-WebApplication'`.

I have tried using the `-Name` parameter label, but then PS complains that `-Name` is used twice in one command.

Comment: It looks like you're adding 2 aliases, `RemPortal` and `portal`. I would use the pattern `Set-Alias -name MyName -value`

Comment: @spikey_richie No, portal is the `-Name` parameter for `Remove-WebApplication` and not for `Set-Alias`. This is the root of my problem. I somehow need to "escape" that parameter label.

Comment: Ok, so then what is RemPortal?

Comment: @spikey_richie `RemPortal` is the desired name of my alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Set-Alias command does not support adding parameters to your command as PowerShell will interpret that as parameters for the Set-Alias rather than parsing them through as the alias.

Instead, you need to create a function, call the new command from there, and use Set-Alias to give that function a new name.

For example:

```
PS> Function remove-webapplication-params {Remove-WebApplication -Name portal -Site "Default Site"}

PS> Set-Alias -Name RemPortal -Value remove-webapplication-params
```

See also example 5 listed at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7